# Glide downloadOnly() as GIF file

Tags: android, gif, android-glide

```
public void downloadImage(final ImageListener imageListener) {
    if (post != null && getContext() != null) {
        FutureTarget<File> future = Glide.with(getContext())
                .downloadOnly()
                .load(post.getPostImage().getUrl())
                .submit(500, 500);

        new GetFileTask(future, imageListener).execute();
    }
}

public static class GetFileTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ImageListener imageListener;
    private FutureTarget<File> futureTarget;

    public GetFileTask(FutureTarget<File> futureTarget, ImageListener imageListener) {
        this.imageListener = imageListener;
        this.futureTarget = futureTarget;
    }

    @Override protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = futureTarget.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            imageListener.onFailure();
        }
        if (file != null) {
            imageListener.onSaveSuccessful(Uri.parse(file.toURI().toString()));
        } else {
            imageListener.onFailure();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Currently this code works great, it'll download the gif but my only issue is the file extension is not .gif, it's .0

When pulling the file from the device and onto my computer, and then renaming from .0 to .gif, it plays the gif flawlessly.

asGif() returns a RequestBuilder, which downloadOnly is deprecated on.. Does anyone know how to request this file to save with the .gif file extension?

Comment: Is this due to caching strategy? Using DiskCacheStrategy.NONE causes a GlideException: Failed to load resource when trying to get the file from the Futures task

Comment: Closed with response from Glide devs saying this is misusing the library: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2891